# Are there any operations/methods in Ruby that are guaranteed/documented to be atomic?

Tags: ruby, concurrency

I did a quick google search, and almost everything written on atomicity in Ruby suggest wrapping a Mutex around the operation. However, I suspect that this approach doesn't satisfy the usual definition of atomicity, since a signal could interrupt synchronized code. For example (taken from [Ruby Best Practices](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/ewong/016-Implementing-Signal-Handlers.html)):

```
lock = Mutex.new

# XXX this is an example of what NOT to do inside a signal handler:
trap(:USR1) do
  lock.synchronize do
    # if a second SIGUSR1 arrives here, this block of code
    # will fire again.   Attempting Mutex#synchronize twice
    # the same thread leads to a deadlock error
  end
end
```

I understand that atomicity is less important for High Level Languages, but for the sake of research I would like to get a canonical answer on this matter for implementations with GIL (e.g. **MRI 2.0.0**) and without *e.g.* **JRuby 1.7.4, and Rubinius 1.2.4**

Comment: What Ruby engine and version?

Comment: Atomic operations in Ruby: http://moonbase.rydia.net/mental/blog/programming/atomic-operations-in-ruby.html

Comment: MRI is very different than JRuby & Rubinius because of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very limited knowledge on this topic. But I will try to answer as best as i can.

There is a very good article that Jesse Storimer wrote about concurrency. I would highly recommend you to read all of 3 parts about it.

http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8100871-nobody-understands-the-gil-part-2-implementation

The conclusion on part 2 is that GIL guaranteed that native C method implementation are atomic.

The example that you gave is actually more of re-entrance problem then atomicity. I don't know  if that is the same thing or how close related it is.

Like the article explain, ruby is different from event driven programming where callback are synchronous, meaning that if you send the signal USR1 twice, the second handler will be executed after the first one finished. So you will not lock on the mutex twice.

But in the signal handling in ruby is asynchronous. meaning that if you send the signal twice. the second handler will interrupt the first handler. Because the first already acquired the lock, then the second handler that try to acquire the same lock will throw an exception. And I believe that this problem is not ruby specific.

One of the way of solving this problem is by creating a queue to do signal handling. Another solution for this is using a method called "self-pipe" trick. Both of the method. are explained in this article by again the awesome Jesse Storimer :

http://rubysource.com/the-self-pipe-trick-explained/

So,
For MRI 2.0.0 is I believe still have GIL, so ruby only guarantee that native C method are atomic.

JRuby is JVM backed so my guess is all of the thread and locking mechanism are implemented on top of JVM

Rubinius 1.2 also still have the GIL so i believe it will be the same as MRI. But Rubinius 2.x remove the GIL. I haven't had much experience with Rubinius so I'm not entirely sure about it.

And to answer the question, if you are working with multi thread application in ruby. Mutex classes should guard that the block will only be executed by single thread at a time.